# Lines getting automatically simplified in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector

I painstakingly follow a complex, windy road, drawing a line using the create features tool. My points are snapped to a line in another layer. I finish the line by double clicking, and many of the vertices I added are lost, simplifying the line to fewer points. As a result, the line no longer follows the natural curve that I had tried to have it follow. The angular line with few vertices are way off from the original road. How do I stop it from doing this?

I repeatedly tried to digitize the line, but this happened every time. If it matters, there are also grids on my map that I can't get rid of either.

Comment: I just added more details. Is this better?

Comment: Since this seems to be a SpatialReference and/or snapping issue, you really need to specify the exact contents of your SpatialReferece and Snapping environments.

Comment: When you created the featureclass, are you sure the xy tolerance is 1mm. Have you tried to create a featureclass inside a geodatabase, if it has the same result?